# UEFI & legacy PXE chain to WDS

Tags: centos, uefi, pxe, wds

I'm making a PXE server (CentOS 7) that will be able to boot legacy and UEFI clients, so far this works fine, but i also want to be able to boot into WDS via the linux PXE, I was somehow able to make this work by adding the following entry into `pxelinux.cfg/default` file:

```
LABEL wds
MENU LABEL WDS
KERNEL pxechain.com
APPEND 192.168.0.105::Boot\x64\wdsnbp.com
```

This works, but, when I boot the PXE server it automatically boots me into the WDS, without going to the menu, if i disable the WDS server it does go to the menu.

Another thing, I'm trying to accomplish the same thing with UEFI boot, but just can't figure out how to make the menuetry.

Any help would be great.

Update:
I've figured out why WDS was booting, it was listening on DHCP, disabling that fixed the issue.
But i still can't boot into WDS from the menu, it startes the proccess but fails everytime.
here's a photo of the error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUs3n.jpg

Answer (score 0):

1. your WDS fails because the DHCP transaction is not providing the required PXE values pointing `to the WDS server`.
2. forget about doing the same under EFI because

   a. pxechain.com (and descendants) are BIOS only apps

   b. Syslinux.efi (6.03) is unable to launch (chainload) EFI apps like bootmgfw.efi